# Angular UI $tooltipProvider setTriggers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to just add a new set of triggers (show and hide) to my Angular UI tooltips. However, they do not work. How should I go about this? Here is a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ihy7PcB2kwvlJgC1QZ9p?p=preview

Relevant code is:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
$tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
    'show': 'hide'
});
}]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I [updated your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Neota75rvy2MMRNV4pFu?p=preview) to make it work, making two key changes:

**Dependency Order**

Changing the dependency load order to load jQuery before the other scripts.  I do not know exactly why that makes a difference, but it does. Before:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

After:

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

**Using Timeout**

Firing the event on timeout, a technique used in the demo referenced below.  Without the timeout, I get an Angular error `$apply already in progress`.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.runmef = function(eventName) {
    $timeout(function () {
      console.log("Toggling tooltip: " + eventName);
      $("#myid").trigger(eventName);
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

**Reference**

The inspiration for this was a [custom tooltip event Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0wEqzz?p=preview) referenced in an [Angular-UI issue discussion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/625). I recommend it.